# Type checking in a dynamic language

Tags: dynamic

As we all know, when we are using a dynamic language such as Python, we don't have to worry about Types. Because dynamic typing let us work without that concern. Even so, we can know the types of variables using the function `type()` (in Python). So my question is: What good do type checking in a dynamic language?

Comment: Try defining the term "dynamic language".  Hint: think about related terms like "type-safe" or "weakly-typed".

Comment: Are you asking what use is the `type()` function is good for?

Comment: Im asking about type checking in dynamic languages in general @tMC

Comment: Why did you tag with a specific language if you're asking in general?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few cases where type checking is something you want to do. Say, for example, you want to work with iterators, but *not* strings - this is a pretty common case. The best way to make that check is to type check if the item is a string:

```
if isinstance(someobj, str):  # basestring in 2.x
    ...
```

We use [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#isinstance) as it allows for subclasses as well as instances of the class itself. Checking directly using `type()` is pretty much universally a terrible idea, but `type()` does have other uses - sometimes you want to access the class of an instance for reasons other than type checking.

It's also worth noting that Python allows the definition of [abstract base classes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) with a subclass hook - this allows `isinstance()` to do a kind of duck type check, where the class is checked for the relevant methods required. For example, if you want to check something is a Sequence, doing `isinstance(obj, collections.Sequence)` is *not* bad, as it's not actually type-checking in a traditional sense, it checks if the object has the functions necesary for the sequence interface (as defined [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes)).

In general, however, type checking should be avoided. In most cases, it's possible to simply try and do what you want, and then catch exceptions if the object can't do what it needs to. Python generally follows the rule of *ask for forgiveness, not permission*, so try it and gracefully handle errors, rather than checking beforehand.

In short: in a dynamic language, we rely on duck-typing. If an object can quack, we can assume it's a duck. 99% of the time, and object that can quack can be treated as a duck, so we are fine. However, in rare cases, another animal that can quack should not be treated as a duck. The only way we can distinguish between them is to type check, and that is OK. Type checking should not be used to check if our animal can quack, however, as we can just try and see (or, if we can't make it quack right now, but still need to operate dependent on it, check directly for the ability to quack, rather than checking for a type we know can quack).

Answer (score 1):

In python everything is an "OBJECT", and inherits some "PROPERTIES" and "METHODS" that give it a uniqueness.

So, type is a "classification" of an object in terms of the "methods" and "properties" that charecterize it. In other words type checking gives us the utility of that object in terms of 
"methods" and "attributes".

a python "list" is a sequence, a python "string" is a sequence but they have different attributes (one mutable and other immutable), following that they have unique methods to manupulate their structure. For example list can grow or diminish in size using 'append' and 'pop', for string they are forbidden. a string's representation may change with 'capitalize' or 'lower' for lists that may not work.

```
>>> i = ""  # i declared string here
>>> i.append("K")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
>>> i.pop()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

similarly,

```
>>> a = [] # a declared a list here
>>> a.lower()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
>>> a.capitalize()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'capitalize'
```

Thanks for reading !

Comment: This is not a good reason for type checking - as always, if you need a mutable sequence, then try it, catch the exceptions if you get an immutable one, or check with the appropriate ABC (which looks for the necessary functions). The reason to type check comes if you have something that is *functionally* indistinguishable, but is different in context - for example, if you want to flatten all iterators to a depth of n, strings will result in endless recursion, so despite the fact that strings are valid iterators, they shouldn't be dealt with. In that case, it's valid to type check.

Comment: rather you going to all answers and proving all of them wrong ... i tried this on python console: 

>>> isinstance("lattyware", __builtins__.help.__class__)
False

That explains :)! what i said is also "iterated" by your post but anyways you made it really impossible for us to say we know python. He asked what good serves type checking and that included every benefit of type checking .. i never walked a scenario of type checking .. but anyways ur blunt words are taken as motivation!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a hierarchical data structure, where each node can be either a leaf, represented as a scalar object, or a subtree represented as an array. If you're writing a function to process all the leaves, it can use a recursive algorithm where it checks the type of each node; if it's an array it iterates over it and recurses, otherwise it processes the node.